# Python-selenium action chains not working in Safari

Tags: angularjs, python-3.x, selenium, safari

I am trying to click on a menu and then a submenu in selenium-python on a Safari Webdriver. No matter what I do, I cannot seem to make the ActionChains do anything whatsoever. Am I doing something wrong or is this an issue with Safari?

I have tried a number of different actions using the ActionsChain, but none of them seem to be working

````
```driver = webdriver.Safari()
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
   url = "someurl.com"
   link_text = "link text"

   driver.get(url)


   driver.maximize_window()
   wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, link_text)))
      ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, link_text)).click().perform()

   print('Hello World')```
````

I expect to see the browser clicking on the element, but I see only the terminal of my program printing 'Hello World'.

Comment: Is there a reason you are clicking with ActionChains instead of just `driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, link_text).click()`?

Comment: I have tried doing that, but I have been having problems doing that and getting a sub-menu.

Comment: That makes sense. Executing Javascript may be more helpful for you here. If you could post some of the HTML surrounding the element you are trying to click, we can try to work out a solution with better luck.

Comment: @SamProschansky what the error your getting? Please share stack trace.

Comment: @Christine I figured out a workaround. I can use action chains it appears, just not on that page, so I navigated to the link url using the driver.get. I can use the action chains on the next page. I will post here if it keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

You could try clicking with JavaScript instead of ActionChains here:

```
element_to_click = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, link_text)))

driver.execute_script(“arguments[0].click();”, element_to_click)
```

Comment: When I do this, I get this: AttributeError: 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'build'

Comment: looks like build() is not valid for Python ActionChains. My apologies, as a few other languages do require it. I’ve updated my answer to try a JavaScript solution instead.